# Testing with Chromium using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I have the following code

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service

chromedriver_path = "/Users/stephen/Downloads/chromedriver2_mac32_0.8/chromedriver"

chromium_path = "/Users/stephen/Downloads/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOs/Chromium"

service = service.Service(chromedriver_path)
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': chromium_path}
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    service.service_url,
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Unfortunately, when I run the above Python script, Selenium very politely completely ignores the fact that I wanted to use `Chromium` and instead uses my default `Google Chrome`. To be clear, it does exactly what the script specifies, it is just that it is using Chrome and not Chromium.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong. I am basing my attempts off of the following pages.

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/GettingStarted

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html?highlight=capabilities

What do I need to do to use the ***Chromium*** web browser with Selenium (in Python)?

Answer (score 17):

The `desired_capabilities` option is for options passed on to the general selenium driver code. Options used by the chrome driver, including the chrome or chromium binary location, are passed in using `chrome_options` as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opts = Options()
opts.binary_location = chromium_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```